# Pickadate - how to actually use selected date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, pickadate

I'm implementing a pickadate date picker, and it's not clear in the docs how to actually use the date a user selects. Eg I have this written:

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    onSet: function(context) {
        console.log(context);
    }
});
```

This produces a weird output (for Sep 8 2015):

```
Object {select: 1441666800000}
```

How is this output actually usable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The weird number is the date returned in milliseconds.

Try this in a console:

```
new Date(1441666800000);

// Returns:
// Mon Sep 07 2015 16:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

Used like this:

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    onSet: function(context) {
        console.log(new Date(context.select););
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What a strange way to return a date. Thanks.

Comment: Serious what is that? Why?

Comment: This didn't work for me. The answer by Lazarev Alexandr worked for me.

Comment: @gregblass I was showing how this "weird output" was actually usable. LazarevAlexandr's answer is also correct and more directly related to the pickadate library.

Comment: @GregBlass me too. This answer is not working for me. Alexandr answer works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735624/pickadate-how-to-actually-use-selected-date#answer-32735774

Answer (score 9):

Your output is a javascript object, with a property `select`. Value of this property is a `timestamp`. Actually this timestamp is amount of milliseconds from the start of unix epoch to the selected day. You can transform in into a date object by using [`Date.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype):

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    onSet: function(context) {
        console.log(new Date(context.select));
    }
});
```

Comment: Cool. Any idea how to get pickadate to not print the chosen date to the input by default?

Comment: How would you go about instead of showing this selected date, you had to capture it in a variable to later use somewhere else? Where does this code goes? I'm sorry for asking on an old answer but I have found only 2 pieces of code that resemble what I need...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/diedsmiling/788d3684b0e8eec804b31cdd7bc9c8e3 something like this, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Exactly right, thank you a lot. It might seem easy but for me that I haven't done this, I was looking in every single wrong place it seems.

Answer (score 6):

You can also make use of the [get select](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#method-get-select) method to get the selected date in a more convenient format. For example when the close event is triggered.

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    onClose: function() {
        console.log(this.get('select', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add datepicker for input field and then on submit button you can store the selcected value to a variable and use variable where you want to show date using jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Datepicker
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});    
    jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });

    $("form").submit(function() {
        var datepickedup = $("input#datepicker").val();
    });
});
```

Where `#datepicker` is input field id.